# Adjusting vertical alignment of underbraces

Tags: vertical-alignment, braces

Is there a way to align multiple underbraces so that they sit on the same horizontal line?
For example, the following code

```
\[
\biggl(
\underbrace{0,1}_{A}, 
\underbrace{\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{3}}_{B}
\biggr)
\]
```

produces this:

[image: underbraces]

But I would like "A" and "B" to be on the same line.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

To align the braces and the text

```
\[
\biggl(
\underbrace{\vphantom{\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{3}}0,1}_{A},
\underbrace{\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{3}}_{B}
\biggr)
\]
```

or to align the text only

```
\[
\biggl(
\mathop{\vphantom{\underbrace{\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{3}}}\underbrace{0,1}}_{A},
\underbrace{\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{3}}_{B}
\biggr)
\]
```