# How to vertically align underbraces

Tags: math-mode, equations, vertical-alignment, braces

I am trying to balance underbraces in the equation below, how can I ensure that both underbraces at the same depth?

```
\begin{equation}
y = \underbrace{ \left [ x^2 + r^2 (a^2+\frac{a^{0.3}}{b}) \right]}_\text{growth rate} \times  \underbrace{ C_0}_\text{initial}
\end{equation}
```

Comment: see also [Adjusting vertical alignment of underbraces](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1733/579)

Answer (score 68, accepted):

One way to solve this is to insert a "vertical phantom" -- an object with a certain height and depth but *no width* and therefore invisible, hence its name "phantom" -- in the second `\underbrace` expression.

In the case at hand, an immediately ready argument for such a `\vphantom` is the tallest "math molecule" from the first `\underbrace` expression; this turns out to be the term `\left(\frac{a^{0.3}}{b}\right)`.

I would also like to suggest that you encase both `\underbrace` expressions in their entirety in curly braces; this'll improve the horizontal spacing around the `\times` symbol.

*Addendum*, Dec. 2019: The word "initial" is wider than the material immediately above it. This causes an unnecessarily wide gap to open up between the material in large square brackets and `C_0`. In the second row of the following screenshot, a `\mathclap` directive is used to set the width of "initial" to 0, leading to a better amount of horizontal spacing.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools} % for '\mathclap' macro
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
y 
&= {\underbrace{%
     \left[ x^2 + r^2 \left(a^2+\frac{a^{0.3}}{b}\right) \right] 
    }_{\text{growth rate}}} 
    \times  
    {\underbrace{%
     \vphantom{ \left(\frac{a^{0.3}}{b}\right) } 
     C_0}_{\text{initial}}}\\
&= {\underbrace{%
     \left[ x^2 + r^2 \left(a^2+\frac{a^{0.3}}{b}\right) \right] 
    }_{\text{growth rate}}} 
    \times  
    {\underbrace{%
     \vphantom{\left(\frac{a^{0.3}}{b}\right)} 
     C_0}_{\mathclap{\text{initial}}}} 
     \qquad \text{with \texttt{\string\mathclap}}\notag
\end{align} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: For the reader (I know Mico knows this already `:-)`): You don't need to put the whole exact same expression into the phantom, you could box it the first time, and then `\copy` the box. Or go with what Werner did in his (now deleted) answer; instead of `\left[<sub expression>\right]`, he used `\bigl[` in the formula, so he just used only `\bigl[` with the phantom, which is shorter to type.

Comment: @morbusg - Indeed, if one happens to know the exact height and depth of the required vphantom, it's certainly much more straightforward to enter this piece of information directly rather than to insert some block of code. :-) At any rate, I wouldn't recommend inserting various phantoms until a very late stage, when the document is almost completely finished. If one starts engaging in visual formatting of this type earlier on, there's a serious risk one will have to redo the phantoms every time a formula changes in some significant way.

Comment: Oh my god, how clever.

Comment: How to use the under brace to specify each term of the above mentioned equation line by line from right to left.