# colored math with the align environment

Tags: color, amsmath

I want different colors for the text and math environments. I use the `align` environment. The code below used to work, but very recently (matter of weeks at most) has broken. Quite frankly, I cannot quite remember why I carry the bit `\def\m@th{\mathsurround\z@\normalcolor}`, which is now causing a break. I may have read about it [there](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48191/is-there-a-way-to-color-only-real-math-in-pdflatex). Because I have forgotten the details, I'm not sure if removing this line of code altogether is the best course.

**Objective**: To have the math in blue and the text under the braces in black (the braces themselves in black is probably better, but either way will do).

**Without the offending code:**

[image]

**With the offending code:**

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\everymath{\color{blue}}
\makeatletter  
\def\m@th{\mathsurround\z@\normalcolor}% Can't remember the reason for this
\makeatother

\begin{document}
Some inline math $C_{0}$.
\begin{align*}
y = {\underbrace{ 
    \left[ x^2 + r^2 \left(a^2+\frac{a^{0.3}}{b}\right) \right] 
    }_\text{growth rate}} \times  
    {\underbrace{ 
    \vphantom{ \left(\frac{a^{0.3}}{b}\right) } C_0
    }_\text{initial}}
\end{align*} 
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To enforce black-coloured text you can add `\color{black}` to the definition of `\textdef@` from `amsmath.sty`.

To change the colour of the braces you can add that to the definition of `\upbracefill` (for `\underbrace`) and `\downbracefill` (for `\overbrace`). But I would go for defining a command, say, `\underbraceColor` that takes an optional argument to change the color.

I also changed `\everymath{\color{blue}}` to `\everymath\expandafter{\the\everymath\color{blue}}` to keep possible previous contents of `\everymath` there:

> [image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\everymath\expandafter{\the\everymath\color{blue}}
\makeatletter
% To enforce black text (taken from amstext.sty)
\def\textdef@#1#2#3{\hbox{{\color{black}%
                    \everymath{#1}%
                    \let\f@size#2\selectfont
                    #3}}}
% To make the braces black (taken from fontmath.sty)
\newcommand{\overbraceColor}[2][.]{%
   \mathop{\vbox{\m@th\ialign{##\crcr\noalign{\kern3\p@}%
   \downbracefillColor{#1}\crcr\noalign{\kern3\p@\nointerlineskip}%
   $\hfil\displaystyle{#2}\hfil$\crcr}}}\limits}
\newcommand{\underbraceColor}[2][.]{%
   \mathop{\vtop{\m@th\ialign{##\crcr
   $\hfil\displaystyle{#2}\hfil$\crcr
   \noalign{\kern3\p@\nointerlineskip}%
   \upbracefillColor{#1}\crcr\noalign{\kern3\p@}}}}\limits}
\def\downbracefillColor#1{$\color{#1}\m@th \setbox\z@\hbox{$\braceld$}%
  \braceld\leaders\vrule \@height\ht\z@ \@depth\z@\hfill\braceru
  \bracelu\leaders\vrule \@height\ht\z@ \@depth\z@\hfill\bracerd$}
\def\upbracefillColor#1{$\color{#1}\m@th \setbox\z@\hbox{$\braceld$}%
  \bracelu\leaders\vrule \@height\ht\z@ \@depth\z@\hfill\bracerd
  \braceld\leaders\vrule \@height\ht\z@ \@depth\z@\hfill\braceru$}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
Some inline math $C_{0}$.
\begin{align*}
y = {\underbraceColor[black]{
    \left[ x^2 + r^2 \left(a^2+\frac{a^{0.3}}{b}\right) \right] 
    }_\text{growth rate}} \times
    {\underbraceColor{
    \vphantom{ \left(\frac{a^{0.3}}{b}\right) } C_0
    }_\text{initial}}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

---

If you prefer to set the color of the braces only once you can use this instead:

```
% To make the braces black (taken from fontmath.sty)
\def\downbracefill{$\color{black}\m@th \setbox\z@\hbox{$\braceld$}%
  \braceld\leaders\vrule \@height\ht\z@ \@depth\z@\hfill\braceru
  \bracelu\leaders\vrule \@height\ht\z@ \@depth\z@\hfill\bracerd$}
\def\upbracefill{$\color{black}\m@th \setbox\z@\hbox{$\braceld$}%
  \bracelu\leaders\vrule \@height\ht\z@ \@depth\z@\hfill\bracerd
  \braceld\leaders\vrule \@height\ht\z@ \@depth\z@\hfill\braceru$}
```

Comment: I went for the shorter code. Coloring under/over braces in the same color as the text makes total sense. Thanks.

Comment: @PatrickT Yes, if you want a document-wise change the second approach requires less effort. You're welcome :)

Answer (score 5):

Redefining `\m@th` is not the best idea. Don't forget `\everydisplay`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\everymath{\color{blue}}
\everydisplay{\color{blue}}
\xpretocmd{\upbracefill}{\blacktext\everymath{\normalcolor}}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\underbrace}{\limits}{\blacktext\limits}{}{}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\blacktext}{%
  \xpatchcmd{\text@}{\mathchoice}{\normalcolor\mathchoice}{}{}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
Some inline math $C_{0}$.
\begin{equation}
y = {\underbrace{ 
    \left[ x^2 + r^2 \left(a^2+\frac{a^{0.3}}{b}\right) \right] 
    }_{\text{growth rate}}} \times  
    {\underbrace{ 
    \vphantom{ \left(\frac{a^{0.3}}{b}\right) } C_0
    }_{\text{initial}}}
\end{equation} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. I have hundreds of pages of ``align`` environments, not ``equation``, is there a way to make this work with ``align``? If I replace ``equation`` with ``align`` the compilation fails with ``! Improper \halign inside $$'s.``

Comment: @PatrickT Yes, remove `\everydisplay{\color{blue}}`. Something else has to be patched if you happen to use `equation`. On the other hand, since you're doing bad typesetting anyway (the colored math), use `align` or `gather` instead of `equation`.

Comment: thanks a lot for your reply. I like that you use ``xpatch``. My clock shows your answer and Phelype's at the same time, and I noticed you have a few more points (!), so I selected his answer. But thank you very much.

Comment: @PatrickT You're welcome! You did well. `:-)`

Answer (score 2):

You can try to pach `\text` as follows (the braces will be in blue but the text in black). The following code needs to replace `_\text{growth rate}` by `_{text{growth rate}}` (nevertheless, for me, `_\text{growth rate}` seems strange).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\everymath{\color{blue}}
\makeatletter  
\let\oldtext@\text@
\def\text@{\color{black}\oldtext@}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
Some inline math $C_{0}$.
\begin{equation}
y = {\underbrace{ 
    \left[ x^2 + r^2 \left(a^2+\frac{a^{0.3}}{b}\right) \right] 
    }_{\text{growth rate}}} \times  
    {\underbrace{ 
    \vphantom{ \left(\frac{a^{0.3}}{b}\right) } C_0
    }_{\text{initial}}}
\end{equation} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: This doesn't work :/

Comment: @Phelype Oleinik : you're right. I have modified my answer.

Comment: Thanks for answering and your comment about the curly braces around the text. I usually do add braces. In this case, I got the math code from Mico's answer linked at the end of this sentence, where the braces were absent. Braces don't seem to be needed in that particular application: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/154329/how-to-vertically-align-underbraces

Comment: Yes, but the syntax is not uniform. You can type `$A_\text{yes}$` but you can't type `$A_\sqrt{2}$`.