# How to put under-braces at same level?

Tags: math-mode, underbrace

I'm trying to put two under-braces in math mode:

```
\underbrace{\frac{5000 \times 1000}{\frac{2 \times 1000 \times 1000 \times 1000}{8}} \times 1000}_\text{transmission time} + \underbrace{13 \times \frac{50}{2}}_\text{wait} = \highlight{345ms}$$
```

However this renders as:

[image]

As you can see, two under-braces are not at the same level. How can I put them at same level?

Comment: Also an option: [Adjusting vertical alignment of `\underbraces`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1733/5764)

Comment: The principle: Use `\vphantom` in areas where you want the same `v`ertical height without explicitly setting something.