# How to align text under the brackets

Tags: vertical-alignment, amsmath, underbrace

How to align text under the brackets:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
\underbrace{(zzz)}_{\textrm{tall}}
\underbrace{zzz}_{\textrm{short}}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: I've taken the liberty of adding a few instructions to your code snippet to make it minimally compilable.

Comment: Since the "deepest" characters in the first and last elements of the expression are the parentheses, I'd simply add `\vphantom{)}` to the middle element.  (This has probably been addressed before, but I didn't look.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton: Yes misalignment is due to descenders in characters. When I try this: `\underbrace{Y(z)}_{\textrm{output}} \underbrace{\vphantom{z^{-1}}}_{\textrm{delay}}`, it's still misaligned. What's wrong? I'm following [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1733/adjusting-vertical-alignment-of-underbraces).

Comment: The `\vphantom` needs to contain something with the required depth, and `z^{-1}` doesn't have any depth.  At first, you'll need to analyze the situation character by character; with time, it becomes automatic.

Comment: Since the example in your question has been changed, I'll try to explain "depth" with reference to the new example.  Locate the baseline -- it is the level on which the *z*, like all letters with no descenders, sits.  The `\underbrace` is placed a fixed distance below the baseline in that case.  But when parentheses are added, they *do* have depth, and the underbrace is placed a fixed distance (the same amount as in the first case) below the lowest point of the parentheses.  When a `\vphantom` is added, that resets the lowest (and highest) point of the expression, moving the underbrace down.

Comment: @barbarabeeton: So what is the code to use in the current example? You said it would be simply adding the `vphantom`.

Comment: Please take a closer look at. my first comment.  There's a parenthesis between those braces: `\vphantom{)}`.  As noted in Mico's answer, that is the same as `\mathstrut`.

Comment: @barbarabeeton: Perfect, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer**

Add the same `\vphantom` spacer to all underbraces, passing it the character with the longest descender. The `\vphantom` itself can be anywhere in the argument of the `\underbrace` command:

```
\underbrace{(zzz)\vphantom{(}}_{\textrm{tall}}
\underbrace{zzz  \vphantom{(}}_{\textrm{short}}
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

**Lyx procedure**

In Lyx, such spacers can be added using menu `Insert | Formatting | Phantom` ([more](https://wiki.lyx.org/FAQ/Spacing#phantom)), or by using the Math Spacing menu from the toolbar:

[image]

Type the text to use as argument, select it and insert the spacer. Spacers appear as red arrows over their grayed argument, which can be edited at any time, the result is updated interactively:

[image: ![enter image description here]

---

**Details**

After some trials I was able to understand how this works, here is a solution not using macros/definitions, because:

- I've only a few occurrences of misalignment.
- I prefer self-contained commands, to keep the code portable from one document to another without the constraint of adjusting header/preamble.

**Cause of the misalignment**

[Underbrace](https://ctex.org/documents/latex/latex2e-html/ltx-335.html) anchors itself to a vertical position which is based on the longest [character descender](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descender). Descenders are these bottom parts of some glyphs extending below the typesetting baseline, e.g. in `y` or `g`.

Hence this anchoring position varies from one underbrace to the other, as their argument is not guaranteed to contain the same descenders. Unfortunately in Latex there is no built-in mechanism for underbraces on the same line to automatically negotiate their vertical position.

**Solution**

The bypass is to add the character with the tallest glyph to all underbraces, so they compute the same vertical position.

However we don't want this additional character to appear. Fortunately there is a helper, `\phantom`, creating a transparent area encompassing whatever is provided for its argument and thus taking into account possible descenders.

The name "phantom" makes sense, since the argument passed to the helper is not displayed and only used to force a spacing.

Of course we are only interested in the vertical space created, we don't want to add an empty horizontal space. There are two variants to `\phantom`, one which exposes only a width (`\hphantom`), one exposing only a height (`\vphantom`). Thus we can use `\vphantom`.

(For the sake of completeness, there is another solution using [rule](https://ctex.org/documents/latex/latex2e-html/ltx-306.html), but said to be "fragile".)

**Choice of vphantom argument**

The argument of `\vphantom` can be anything, usually one character. We choose the character with the longest descender in all underbraces.

Alphabetic characters with long descenders: `jpqy({[|]})`.

Note actual bounding box depends on the glyph, thus on the font used. In particular numbers in fonts with [oldstyle](https://www.fonts.com/content/learning/fontology/level-3/numbers/oldstyle-figures) glyphs for numerals have long descenders, and some glyphs like for `s` can have a decorative swash. So using `(` or `)` is not guaranteed to succeed in specific cases. A word-processing application with decent wysiwyg is helpful.

In math formulas, there are chances some symbol will be the choice (symbols such as integral may be chosen, *including their limits*).

Nothing prevents to pass multiple characters and let the feature compute the outmost bounding box by itself.

**Final code**

Replace this code:

```
\underbrace{(zzz)_{\textrm{tall}}
\underbrace{zzz }_{\textrm{short}}
```

by:

```
\underbrace{(zzz)\vphantom{(}}_{\textrm{tall}}
\underbrace{zzz\vphantom{(}}  _{\textrm{short}}
```

---

Thanks to Barbara, Mico and egreg for suggesting good elements to build this answer. Look at their answers as well, they contain alternatives which may suit your needs.

Comment: Please see the addendum I posted below my answer. Your proposed adjustment "works" because the glyphs `(` and `|` happen to have the same depth if Computer Modern Math is the math alphabet in use; this need not be the case for other math fonts. To "play it safe", I'd suggest using `\vphantom{(}` instead of `\vphantom{|}` in the first argument of `\underbrace`.

Comment: @Mico: You're right, this choice is better. Answer edited.

Answer (score 10):

You want to make the formulas to have the same height. Here I use `\mathstrut`, but in the optional argument you may use any `\vphantom`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\ubracetext}[3][\mathstrut]{%
  \mathinner{%
    \underbrace{#1#2}_{\textrm{\vphantom{X}#3}}%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\ubracetext{Y(z)}{output} =
\ubracetext{z^{-1}}{delay}
\ubracetext{X(z)}{input}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

In case of need you can do

```
\ubracetext[\vphantom{<formula>}]{top}{bottom}
```

Note that spaces in the final argument (the subscript) are honored; don't add them just to keep alignment in the source code.

Comment: Can it be done without a custom command?

Comment: `\mathstrut` is not a custom command.

Comment: @mins Yes, of course, but why?

Comment: I use Lyx and don't know about defining macros. @Mico, I mean `\newcommand{\ubracetext}`.

Comment: @mins You should learn (or avoid LyX). Do you like to type in `\underbrace{\mathstrut Y(z)}_{\textrm{\vphantom{X}input}}`? I don't.

Comment: @egreg: In that case there only to add `\vphantom{X}`.

Answer (score 10):

The reason the middle of the three underbraces isn't aligned vertically with the other two is that the first argument of the associated `\underbrace` directive doesn't contain material that protrudes below the baseline; in contrast, the first arguments of the first and third `\underbrace` directive contain `(` and `)`.

To fix this issue, I suggest you insert the instruction `\mathstrut` -- which is defined as `\vphantom{)}` -- next to `z^{-1}`. I would also use `\textnormal` (or `\textup`) instead of `\textrm`. And I'd use a `\mathclap` directive to let the word "output" to the left and right of the associated brace.

And, for the utmost in typesetting class, insert `\vphantom{d}` directives (`\vphantom{l}` will do too) in the second arguments of the first and third `\underbrace` directives.

If your document contains a lot of these expressions, I'd consider creating a custom macro -- along the lines given in [@egreg's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/680532/5001) -- to simplify and standardize creating these underbrace expressions.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools} % for \mathclap macro
\begin{document}
\[
\underbrace{Y(z)} _{\mathclap{\textnormal{output\vphantom{d}}}} =
\underbrace{z^{-1}\mathstrut} _{\textnormal{delay}}\,
\underbrace{X(z)} _{\textnormal{input}\vphantom{d}}
\]
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum* -- I just noticed that the OP has changed and simplified their query. As a result, the specifics of the answer given above may no longer be all that useful. However, the *principles* that underlie the suggested adjustmens remain the same. Take the OP's new code block:

```
\[
\underbrace{(zzz)}_{\textrm{tall}}
\underbrace{zzz}_{\textrm{short}}
\]
```

Observe that the first argument of the first `\underbrace` directive contains `(`, which protrudes below the baseline, whereas the first argument of the second `\underbrace` directive does not. To fix the resulting difference in the depths at which the horizontal braces are placed, insert a `\mathstrut` directive in the second line:

```
\[
\underbrace{(zzz)}_{\textrm{tall}}
\underbrace{zzz\mathstrut}_{\textrm{short}}
\]
```

This works perfectly because `\mathstrut` is defined as as `\vphantom{(}`, which is a typographic strut with some height and (importantly) depth -- and no width, which makes it invisible, justifying the "phantom" part in `\vphantom`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for '\underbrace' and '\text' macros
\begin{document}
\[
\underbrace{(zzz)}_{\textrm{tall}}  \underbrace{zzz}_{\textrm{short}}
\quad\text{vs.}\quad
\underbrace{(zzz)}_{\textrm{tall}}\,\underbrace{zzz\mathstrut}_{\textrm{short}}
\]
\end{document}
```